# React Native - How to access props passed though navigation.navigate()

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

When I use a component function as shown below, I'm able to access `data` passed through `navigation.navigate("NavigateToScreen", {data: {}})` function in the following:

```
import { useNavigation } from '@react-navigation/native';

export default function ScreenName(props) {

   const data = props.route.params.data;

   const navigation = useNavigation();

}
```

How do I access `data` in target screen when receiving screen is as follows:

```
export default function ScreenName({ navigation }) {

   const data = //How do I receive props here

}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can access them through the `route` parameter:

```
export default function ScreenName({ navigation, route }) {

   const { data } = route.params;

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can access them using the `route` parameter or check out the `useRoute` hook. [Follow this link for a detailed explanation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/use-route/)